# prove that $\;f(z) = g(z)\;$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

The problem is:

Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be entire such that  $r>0 ,\; f(z) = g(z)$  for all $|z| < r.  $

- Prove that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Does that mean I should prove that the function is polynomial ?

I am thinking that's because it's bounded by a polynomial ??

Since $f$ is entire, it is equal to a power series centered at zero with radius of convergence $\infty$, which must match its Taylor series there.

Comment: Look up “identity theorem for holomorphic functions.”

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_permanence

Comment: thanks @MartinR that's really useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider the function $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$, then $h(z)$ will also be analytic on the entire $\mathbb{C}$. By the hypothesis, $h(z)=0$ in a disc $|z|<r$. Since the zeroes of an analytic function which does not vanish identically are $\textit{isolated}$, and the disc $|z|<r$ has accumulation points in $\mathbb{C}$ hence the function $h(z)$ is identically $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Welcome new contributor. What do you mean by [in fact in the complement of the disc] ? the set of accumulation points of $\{|z|<r\}$ is in fact the closed disk  $\{|z|\leq r\}$

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have much to do. I made that point to stress the fact that even if the set, $S$ on which $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ agree, is not as nice as the disc, still we can have the above result. If the set just has one accumulation point in $\mathbb{C}-S$, i.e. there is a sequence of zeroes which converges to a point which is outside $S$, then the function must agree entirely. It would be a nice exercise to prove that the number of zeroes of an analytic function can't be infinite. :-)

Comment: [It would be a nice exercise to prove that the number of zeroes of an analytic function can't be infinite]--->This can occur (i.e. the exercise would be false) take $f(z)=e^z-1$ which has $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$ as set of zeroes.

Comment: I have edited your answer, now it is correct (+1) In mathematics, not only _the intention counts_, the text must be locally exact (well, as much as possible, we are humans :)

Comment: Thankyou @Duchamp Gérard H. E. Yeah the infinite number of zeros can occur. Well I am new to this forum, so I need to be precise in my upcoming answers. Thank you 